# access object through dot-syntax string path

Tags: javascript

How can I access `myobject[path][to][obj]` via a string `path.to.obj`? I want to call a function `Settings.write('path.to.setting', 'settingValue')` which would write `'settingValue'` to `settingObj[path][to][setting]`. How can I do this without `eval()`?

I finally figured it out around the same time as one of the users below answered it. I'll post mine here with documentation on how it works if anyone is interested.

```
(function(){
    var o = {}, c = window.Configure = {};

    c.write = function(p, d)
    {
        // Split the path to an array and assaign the object
        // to a local variable
        var ps = p.split('.'), co = o;

        // Iterate over the paths, skipping the last one
        for(var i = 0; i < ps.length - 1; i++)
        {
            // Grab the next path's value, creating an empty 
            // object if it does not exist
            co = (co[ps[i]])? co[ps[i]] : co[ps[i]] = {};
        }

        // Assign the value to the object's last path
        co[ps[ps.length - 1]] = d;
    }

    c.read = function(p)
    {
        var ps = p.split('.'), co = o;
        for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++)
        {
            co = (co[ps[i]])? co[ps[i]] : co[ps[i]] = {};
        }
        return co;
    }
})();
```

The reason I was having problems is you have to skip the last path. If you include the last path, you end up just assigning an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.split()` for that:

```
path = pathString.split('.');
settingObj[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]] = settingValue;
```

`str.split()` will separate the variable into an array, split at the locations of the character you specify.

This is just the root of the operation of course, and assumes proper input.

**Edit**: Since the paths need to be of variable length, here's an updated version edited from the syntax you've shown above:

```
(function(){
    var o = {}, c = window.Configure = {};

    c.write = function(p, d)
    {
        var ps = p.split('.'), co = o;
        for(var i = 0; i < ps.length - 1; i++)
        {
            co = (co[ps[i]])? co[ps[i]] : co[ps[i]] = {};
        }
        co[ps[ps.length-1]] = d;
    }

    c.read = function(p)
    {
        var ps = p.split('.'), co = o;
        for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++)
        {
            co = (co[ps[i]])? co[ps[i]] : co[ps[i]] = {};
        }
        return co;
    }

    c.write('path.to.property', 'setting');
    alert(c.read('path.to.property'));
})();
```

Comment: but you never know exactly how many parts to the path there are. Could be 2, could be 6.

Comment: My bad, I assumed it was some sort of pre-existing setting or something. I put the code in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HVh7X/, which I started before seeing your edit, so I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: lol, yeah, just figured it out. I needed to skip the last path, cause I was just assigning a arbitrary value. As soon as you edit your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: warning, your above code will overwrite any object, even if you are trying to append to it. Line 9 and 10 should be changed to `co = (co[ps[i]])? co[ps[i]] : co[ps[i]] = {};`

Comment: Good point. I hadn't thought of pre-existing settings paths. Edited, should be right now. Thanks for marking it as answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `co` contains a reference to your property, but when you update the value of `co` with `co = p` you are just overwriting the value of `co`, not the value of the property.  You need to keep a reference to the last key, and use that key to set the value:

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/a2p8m/1/

```
c.write = function(p, d) 
{ 
    var ps = p.split('.'), co = o, key; 
    for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) 
    { 
        if (key)
        {
            co = (key in co) ? co[key] : co[key] = {};
        }
        key = ps[i];
    } 
    co[key] = d; 
    console.log(co); 
    console.log(o); 
}
```

You may want to use `key in co` instead of just doing a "truthy" check.  Otherwise, a value of `1`, will be retained while a value of `0` will be overwritten with `{}`.  Then again, either of those values would result in a runtime error for the above code, since you can't write a property onto a number.  Best would be to check `typeof co[key]`.

```
co = co[key] && /object|function/.test(typeof co[key]) ? co[key] : co[key] = {};
```

(I know I'm a little late with my answer, but I figure after putting all that effort in typing with my thumbs, I might as well include it anyway)

<s>I suspect you are encountering a grouping error.  Try moving the end paren in your ternary expression to the end of the line:</s>

```
co = (co[ps[i]] ? co[ps[i]] : co[ps[i]] = {});
```

I'd test this myself but I'm answering from my mobile and jsfiddle is tedious when typing with just thumbs.