# is it evil to use eval to convert a string to a function?

Tags: javascript

I have heard lot's of different opinions on eval() and are a bit unsure if it's ok to use eval() in this context:

let's say I have an object like this:

```
var bla = {
blubb: function (callback) {
       //GET some stuff via ajax
       //call the callback
    }
}
```

And a string like this:

```
 var someString = "bla.blubb";
```

Is it evil to eval the string in order to call the function (and the callback)?

```
var callMe = eval(someString)
callMe(function(){
   alert('yay')!
});
```

Comment: It's a felony in ten states....

Comment: Where is the string coming from and why can't it just point directly to `bla.blubb`?

Comment: The problem isn't eval there, as it can be easily replaced by a simple parsing, but the whole design which lets you call any function on any object.

Comment: if you try to keep a "function pointer" then you should directly set the variable to the expected function `var callMe = bla.blubb;`.
There are a few cases where you are forced to call eval on a string but this does not seem one of them.

Another solution would be something like (assuming bla is a global):
`var callMe = window; for (var key in someString.split('.')) callMe = callMe[someString.split('.')[key]];` to do the parsing manually...

Answer (score 5):

> i have heard lot's of different opinions on eval()

`eval` is not evil in general, there are applications for it.

> unsure if it's ok to use eval() in this context

No, it is not OK for this. There is a much better solution using the simple [bracket notation member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). Since this is asked every day on SO, I can list hundreds of dupes here (just the first few Google results):

- [Convert string in dot notation to get the object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934664/convert-string-in-dot-notation-to-get-the-object-reference)
- [Convert javascript dot notation object to nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793811/convert-javascript-dot-notation-object-to-nested-object)
- [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)
- [access object through dot-syntax string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338192/access-object-through-dot-syntax-string-path)
- [Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)
- [Access object child properties using a dot notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string)
- [Access property via it's keyPath in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17683616/1048572)
- …

Comment: +1 for so many references...

Comment: It was really just [Google](http://www.google.de/search?q=stackoverflow+javascript+dot+string+object+access). All results were valid, though...

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation of eval ;). And thank's for the links, I now know how to say it in english (pretty hard to explain an issue being french :p).

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose your whole design isn't totally evil (but a little).

That would mean you restrict and specify what you have in `someString`. For example it could be the path to an object and its function that you would call **without any argument** (which makes it much less dangerous) and with context the global object.

Then it's easy to parse the string and call the function without `eval`. This would be more secure. For example :

```
window.a = {b:{c:function(){console.log('here')}}};
var someString = "a.b.c";

var path = someString.split('.');
var f = window;
for (var i=0; i<path.length; i++) f = f[path[i]];
f.call(null);
```

An improvement would be to fix a root object (and not window) to avoid any kind of call.

Comment: by the time I typed my comment you came up with the same idea :) definitely the best option for me, you got my vote !

Comment: A link to one of the many dupes might have fit better than rewriting this snippet over and over :-) See my answer

Comment: @Bergi I didn't knew this was a dupe... Sorry it's a first for me...

Comment: It's a little worrying that so many people ask the same thing. This kind of coupled mapping isn't generally the basis for a sound application...

Answer (score 0):

It's evil again because it's hard for debugging.
Better approach is to use something like:

```
function getValue(namespace, parent) {
    var parts = namespace.split('.'),
        current = parent || window;
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 1) {
        if (current[parts[i]]) {
            current = current[parts[i]];
        } else {
          if (i >= parts.length - 1)
            return undefined;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
var foo = {
    bar: {
        baz: function () { alert('baz'); }
    }
};
var f = getValue('foo.bar.baz'); //true
if (typeof f === 'function') {
    f();
}
```

The code is more than a single `eval('foo.bar.baz')` but you can figure out what's actually happening and even debug it with break points.

If we speak about performance here are few jsperf examples:

1. http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-loop
2. http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-loop/2

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget you can use a "safe eval" in javascript if you know what your objects will look like.

inside a scope :

```
this.foo = { bar:function(){return "baz"}};

// some code.
var obj = "foo";
var param = "bar";

this[obj][param](); // same as this.foo.bar();
```

Unless you are dealing with some specific things (like templating for instance) ,you should not need to use eval to call objects.

Comment: That is not "safe eval", that's just a member operator.

Comment: that's why i put quote around the expression "safe eval" , but it is still evaluating a string and looking up to the related member of the object, sounds like string evaluation to me.

Comment: That's how hash maps works, it's just a key, not evaluated.

Comment: No. The string is not *evaluated*, that's the point. It's just a lookup operation.

Comment: try do a["5"] with an array , it's not just a lookup operation.