# Proper use of eval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, eval

So I have this json object where the structure is variable depending on how you retrieve the data.  Lets say the object looks like this in one case:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "users": [...]
  }
}
```

but looks like this in another case:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "posts": [...]
  }
}
```

Now for the first example, they way I am dynamically getting the data is like this:

```
var dataLocation = 'data.users';
var responseData;
eval('responseData = response.' +dataLocation + ';');
```

This allow me to configuration it.  Just note that this is just a simple example, in the real code there is only one function to parse the data and I would be passed dataLocation in as a parameter.

Now my first question is whether or not there is a better want to accomplish the same goal without using eval?

If not, the second question is what do I need to do to the eval statement to make sure it is safe (dataLocation should never be passed in from a user, it will always come from code but still).

***UPDATE***

Based on the comment from Bergi, I am now using this:

```
var parts = dataListLocation.split('.');

for(var x = 0; x < parts.length; x += 1) {
  responseData = responseData[parts[x]];
}
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [is it evil to use eval to convert a string to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396647/is-it-evil-to-use-eval-to-convert-a-string-to-a-function)

Comment: See [thousand ways to do this better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

You should use bracket notation instead of `eval`:

```
var responseData = response['data']['users'];
```

Note: from your description, what you have is a JavaScript object literal. A JSON would be that same object encoded as a string (with `JSON.stringify`, for example). There is no such thing as a "JSON object", you either have a JavaScript object, or a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key indexers for objects in JS:

```
var responseData response.data['users]';
```

That is after getting rid of the `data.` in our dataLocation