# How to modify nested value with a single variable as multiple keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary like this (this is just example data):

```js
obj = {
    name: 'John',
    properties: {
       age: 42,
       address: 'somewhere'
    }
}
```

What if I wanted to **modify a value of any depth, specified by a variable**?

For depth 1 it would be direct:

```js
obj[what_to_modify] = new_value
```

but for depth > 1?

```js
what_to_modify="properties.age"
obj[what_to_modify.split('.')] = new_value
// I KNOW, THIS DOESN'T WORK, IT JUST
// ILLUSTRATES WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
```

My solution was to do a foor lop like this:

```js
let levels = what_to_modify.split('.')
let it = obj
for(let k=0; k < levels.length; k++){
    let key = levels[k]
    if(k == levels.length -1){
        it[key] = new_value
    }else{
        it = it[key]
    }
}
```

This already works, but I wanted to know: **Is there a less messy way to do it?**

---

To be clear, I don't want to just read the value, I want to *modify* it, so [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path) and [Access property via it's keyPath in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683616/access-property-via-its-keypath-in-javascript) don't solve my problem

---

**IMPORTANT**

The accepted answer uses lodash, but actually I shouldn't include new dependencies in my project, so if there's any other way with vanilla JS, I will change the accepted answer to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access property via it's keyPath in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683616/access-property-via-its-keypath-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Comment: @DamiaanDufaux It would if it allowed me to modify it, not only to read it

Comment: @mdeamf same as with Damian, but also it's as messy as my proposed solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/). `_.set` sets a value by path and `_.get` returns a value by path. `_.toPath` converts a string to a path array.

```js
const obj = {
    name: 'John',
    properties: {
       age: 42,
       address: 'somewhere'
    }
};

const propertiesAgePath = _.toPath('properties.age');
console.log(_.get(obj, propertiesAgePath));
_.set(obj, propertiesAgePath, 43);
console.log(_.get(obj, propertiesAgePath));
_.set(obj, _.toPath('properties.address'), 'new address');
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm going to upvote and accept, but actually I shouldn't include new dependencies to the project I'm working on, so if there's any other answer that can do that for me without lodash, I will have to change it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Miguel That's very sad that so many people insist in reinventing the wheel. That's a solved problem and lodash has so many helpful tools that I add it to most projects I'm working in. It's great for deep clones, creating ranges, complex object modifications, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can also *carefully* use eval to accomplish this.

```
let new_value = 9

obj = {
    name: 'John',
    properties: {
       age: 42,
       address: 'somewhere'
    }
}

what_to_modify="properties.age"

eval("obj."+what_to_modify+"= new_value")

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Please read [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Comment: I'm not going to include eval in my code, but thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: eval is dangerous depending on what you put in there. Understand your desire to not use it.

Comment: It's not only dangerous but also slow. It can easily be replaced with functions with better performance.