# JS reference multi-layered dynamic object string

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a string that references a deep Javascript object, such as:

```
var string = 'response.basicInfo.gender';
```

I want to build a function that safely checks if that object exists, by splitting the string by `.`s and building the object, checking each level as it goes, and then dealing with the value of the object, if it actually exists.

```
var parseHelper = function(response, items) {
  for (item in items) {
    var parts = String(item).split('.');
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
      // ... etc. build the string
    }
  }
}

parseHelper(response, {
  'basicInfo.gender': function(val){
    return (val == 'M') ? 'Male' : (val == 'F') ? 'Female' : val;
  },
})
```

While the above function is incomplete, let's suppose we use it to build the string and check if each exists:

```
// so let's suppose we build the string:
var builtString = "response['basicInfo']";

// Now we want to check if it exists 
if (response['basicInfo']) {

  // And if we are fine that it exists, go on to the next item
  var builtString = "response['basicInfo']['gender']";

  // etc.
}
```

I don't have a problem building that function, I just don't know how to evaluate a string like `"response['basicInfo']['gender']"` and turn it into an actual reference to the object. My only guess would be eval(), but eval is evil...

#### Update

I know you can reference a global object by going `window['blah']`, but this response object I want to reference is not in the global scope, so do I use `this`? And even if I can do this, how do I reference it with multiple layers?

Comment: You cannot without `eval`. You need a base object (`response` in your case) *and* a property list.

Comment: Can you give me some sort of code sample?

Comment: [There are many](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572). All of these functions take an object for the base reference and a string (or list of strings) for the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plus 1 to Bergi, who linked to a page with six links, one of which had an answer I adapted to solve the problem:

[Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)

Here's the full solution.

```
// We want to run a parse function to convert
// the object response.basicInfo.gender (which is 'M')
// to 'Male', etc.

// Sets the value of a string representing a deep object.
setDeep: function(root, path, value) {
  var parts = path.split('.'), obj = root;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; ++i) {
    obj = obj[parts[i]] || { };
  }
  obj[parts[parts.length - 1]] = value;
  return obj;
},

// Gets the value of a string representing a deep object.
getDeep: function(root, path) {
  var parts = path.split('.'), obj = root, target;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
   target = obj[parts[i]];
   if (typeof target == "undefined") return void 0;
   obj = target;
  }
  return obj;
},

// Loops through multiple string representations
// of deep objects and runs the values through 
// assigned parsing functions for each of them,
// returning the root object.
parseHelper: function(obj, items) {
  for (item in items) {
    var val = getDeep(obj, item);
    var func = items[item];
    if (val !== undefined) {
      val = func(val);
    }
    setDeep(obj, item, val);
  }
  return obj;
},

// response.basicInfo.gender = 'M';
// response.foo.bar = true;

response = parseHelper(response, {
  'basicInfo.gender': function(val){
    return (val == 'M') ? 'Male' : (val == 'F') ? 'Female' : val;
  },
  'foo.bar': function(val) {
    return (val) ? false : true;
  },
});

// response.basicInfo.gender = 'Male';
// response.foo.bar = false;
```