# jQuery: converting object["student.course.name"] to object['student']['course']['name']

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending server sent data to table, showing selected/nested object attributes. I am facing difficulty in providing correct multi-dimensions to fetch correct data member.
**Scenario:** I'm having a `json` object, whose properties I need to fetch inside JavaScript. Script key (say, 'student.course.name') any length long member access hierarchy.
   ***input:*** `"student.course.name"`
   ***To be used as:***  `someObject['student']['course']['name']` 
***possible input keys***: `"age", "dept.name", "student.college.university.name" etc.`

I've tried `.split()` and `for loop` but none fulfills all the possible requirement. Please suggest changes!

Comment: Do you actually have the item as object in JavaScript? Or is it a string, separated by `.` that you wish to convert to an array? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: *"I'm having a `json` object..."* It's just an object. You have have the object because you parsed JSON text, but once that text is parsed, it's just an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS reference multi-layered dynamic object string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964074/js-reference-multi-layered-dynamic-object-string)

Answer (score 4):

If you really have the string `"student.course.name` and you really have an object that has a property called `student`, which in turn has a property called `course`, which in turn has a property called `name`, e.g.:

```
var key = "student.course.name";
var someObject = {
    student: {
        course: {
            name: "the name"
        }
    }
};
```

Then this works:

```
var keys = key.split(".");
console.log(someObject[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]]);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/OQUsitUS/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/OQUsitUS/1/edit)

Or the indefinite-depth version:

```
var keys = key.split(".");
var value = someObject;
var n;
for (n = 0; n < keys.length; ++n) {
    value = value[keys[n]];
}
console.log(value);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/OQUsitUS/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/OQUsitUS/3/edit)

We start with `value = someObject`, and for each key, we grab the relevant property from `value` and assign it to `value`. So on the first pass, `value` becomes the `student` object; on the second pass, it's `course`; and on the third and final pass, it's the value of `name`.