# access object property by variable with more than one "nodes" in javascript

Tags: javascript

Imagine this object:

```
var obj = {
             one: {
                two:{
                    three: "whatever"
                }
             }
          }
```

If I want to access "whatever" I simply do:

```
console.log( obj.one.two.three ) --> "whatever"
```

And I can even use a variable like:

```
var one = "one"
console.log( obj[one].two.three ) --> "whatever"
```

But why doesn't this work ?

```
var onetwo = "one.two"
console.log( obj[onetwo].three ) --> undefined
```

Comment: It would have to be `obj[one]["two"].three`. Notice that dots in property names are allowed, so `["one.two"]` is a single property that cannot be written in dot notation.

Comment: yes but that would only work if I knew the exact amount of "nodes"

Comment: If you don't, you will need to use a loop over the "node" names. There is no expression for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why doesn't this work ?

Because the notation is not supported in the language. It's simply not there. The specification defines [property access as with bracket notation](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1) as:

> MemberExpression [ Expression ]

The algorithm for defining how that works is defined in the lines below, the syntax for nested properties is simply not a part of the core language syntax.

There are specific parsers that let you do this, and you can always invoke the language compiler yourself (JS lets you do that with `eval` for example - don't though), but the use case is not common enough.

---

Note:
Since you mentioned in the comments you use Angular, it already has that built in using `$parse` doing `var res = $parse("one.two.three")(obj);` Here's [**a fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FNM6v/)

Comment: damn, do you know of a parser for this ? I am currently working with angular btw

Comment: @PedroEsperança: There are [many answers here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572)

Comment: @PedroEsperança Angular let's you do this of course, the use case is quite common in Angular, for example in a binding with `{{obj.propertyone.propertytwo}}` this sort of parsing and scope resolution is done. Check out [`$parse`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse) . It converts an Angular expression into a function.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a way to do this with parse, could you shed any lights?

Comment: @PedroEsperança Sure, your code will probably look difference since you can just get $parse inside wherever you need it anyway instead of using the injector explicitly. In a line it's - `var res = $parse("one.two.three")(obj);` Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/FNM6v/

Comment: worked like a charm :)
the problem now is that I am not being able to change the values on the service :p

I am using this like: $parse("path to item")(injectedservice)
It gives me a ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment :s

Comment: @PedroEsperança that sounds like a new question to me. I don't want to go on and discuss a new topic on the same question. Please consider opening a new question about that if it's not clear to you. (Include a fiddle while you're at it - ReferenceError seems unlikely if that's all there is to it). Note that the syntax for changing and the syntax for retrieving in $parse is different (with .assign - see the docs).

Comment: thank you so much @BenjaminGruenbaum 
can I ask what you are working on ?
add me anywhere: buesimples@gmail.com

Comment: @PedroEsperança Several things, I would not publish my email here if I were you. SO is a public site. Anyway, discussion in comments is frowned upon in Stack Overflow. I'm often in [the JavaScript chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) , you're welcome to find me there :)