# Getting an Objects nested value from an array of nested properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I have a situation where I need to zip two Objects together retaining both of the values. I can iterate through both the objects and build an array of all the keys.

```
    var traverse = function (obj, chain) {

        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

                var tempChain = [].concat(chain || []);
                tempChain.push(prop);

                if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
                    traverse(obj[prop], tempChain);
                }
                console.log(tempChain);
            }
        }
    };
```

Passing in the following:

```
    traverse({
        'a': {
            'b': 'hello world',
            'b1': 'hello world 1',
            'c': {
                'd': 'dello'
            }
        }
    })
```

Will return me:

```
[a]
[a,b]
[a,b1]
[a,c]
[a, c, d]
```

So I now have an array of nested properties in an object. How can I access essentially obj[[a,c,d]]? I know I can solve the problem through eval but I can't trust the content.

```
eval('window.' + ['a','c','d'].join('.'));
```

If I can loop through that array and check to see if the property exists in both of them, then build a new object of the combined 'zipped' values.

Comment: `window !== obj`, that wouldn't work anyway. But yes, you can use a simple loop.

Comment: Check [any of these duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572) - just omit the `.split(".")` as you have an array already

Comment: I think this is some kind of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly is your `zip` supposed to do, and why would you need property chains for that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
function getValueAt(obj, keyPathArray) {
    var emptyObj = {};

    return keyPathArray.reduce(function (o, key) {
        return (o || emptyObj)[key];
    }, obj);
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var o = { a: { c: { d: 1 } } };

getValueAt(o, ['a', 'c', 'd']); //1
```

However it's not efficient for non-existing properties, since it will not short-circuit.
Here's another approach without using `reduce`:

```
function getValueAt(o, keyPathArray) {
    var i = 0, 
        len = keyPathArray.length;

    while (o != null && i < len) o = o[keyPathArray[i++]];

    return o;    
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `while (o!=null && i<l) o = o[keyPathArray[i++]];`? Currently you will always return `undefined` when `i` exceeds the length, and it will fail when `o` becomes `null` somewhere.

Comment: I've tried using both your solutions however the function returns the value and I want the object pointing to the value. To give a better explanation heres some working code which are using evals. http://jsbin.com/EHeFayu/7/

Comment: @Bergi, Yeah, somehow I haven't tought that the last value could be an object and that typeof `null` was 'object'. Silly mistakes. Fixed.

Comment: @dtsn, I cannot access jsbin right now, however I believe you could just ignore the last element in the array and it will return the object holding that property. `var keyPath = ['a', 'b', 'c']; keyPath = keyPath.slice(0, keyPath.length - 1); getValueAt(o, keyPath);` Obviously you have to hold a reference to the root object.