# Reference JSON Object Using String Path - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

How can I get the value of json object using a series of keys stored in a string.
So in this object :

```
var data = {
 "user":{
    "profiles":{
       "facebook":{
          "id":765764
       }
    }
 }
}
```

I can reference the facebook object this way :

```
data.user.profiles.facebook; // = Object{id: 765764}
```

but what if I have the keys saved in a string like this :

```
var key = "user.profiles.facebook";
data[key]; // does not work unless the string contains only one key.
```

I need to reference the object where I can modify/change it.

```
data[key]= {};// for example
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Found a dup where I posted an answer to this very problem.

Comment: @elclanrs: [It's not the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572) :-)