# Call function dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to dynamically call a function from a string like "User.find". A script would call the function find() in the object User if the function exists. Here's what I tried:

```
 var User = {};
 User.find = function(){
     return 1;
 }

 var input = 'User.find';
 var some_data_array = {name: 'John Doe'};
 var method = input.toString().split('.');
 var nameObj = method[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + method[0].substring(1);
 var methodToCall = method[1];

 nameObj.call(methodToCall, some_data_array);
```

But it always returns:

```
 nameObj.call(methodToCall, some_data_array);
 TypeError: Object User has no method 'call'
```

Any idea? I can't use window since it is a node.js problem, the script is not executed in the browser.

Comment: `nameObj` is a *string*, not a function?

Comment: when it comes to dynamic, try using `eval`.

Comment: That's why I'm asking here. I don't know how to call a function from a dynamic object.

Comment: @KingKing: No; don't use `eval`.

Comment: Yes I want to avoid using eval.

Comment: @SLaks it's usable in some cases and in fact without it, you cannot solve the problem (I don't mean in this case, but probably in some case).

Comment: @Codel96 the method name is a string (input from user), but I'm not sure what exactly the object is here? (you want to convert `"User"` string to an object? weird without any context).

Comment: The thing is User exists as an object, and so does its function "find". I just edited my first post.

Comment: This question is tagged nodejs. Does it have to be node or is a browser-centric solution acceptable?

Comment: It is a node issue because it isn't running in the browser. I want to call the function from the server-side.

Comment: you can try defining some root object. Define the `User` property in that object, then you can access the `User` like this `root["User"]`, next you can access the `find` like this `root["User"]["find"](...)`

Comment: Have a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're completely misunderstanding `call()`.

`call()` lets you call a method with a different `this`.

You want to get as property by name:

```
object[methodName](arg1, arg, ...);
```

Comment: Thank's for answering but it doesn't work for me : http://jsfiddle.net/74kmm6bp/ or maybe I didn't get how to use it.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. At least the OP's problem is unclear now. He does not even have any ***right*** object here, as well as some reference to the method (just method name).

Comment: @Codel96: `nameObj` is a string.  To get the global variable by that name, use the same syntax: `window[nameObj]`.

Comment: I can't use window since the script is not executed in the browser but with node.js. I just edited with a more clear explanation of the problem.

Comment: @Codel96: Then put the variables that may be accessed in a separate object, and use that.  That's better for security, anyway.

Comment: Ok I didn't really think about that. That way I can even check if the function really exists easily.

Comment: @KingKing: That's because JSFiddle wraps the code in a function, so those are locals.

Answer (score 3):

You actually can achieve this. You first would need to get the `scope`, where your namespace/function/object is defined.

For example, in your code I would assume its `window`.

So, a little modification of your code would produce the desired result:

```
var User = {};
User.find = function(x){
    alert(x);
}

 var input = 'User.find';
 var some_data_array = {name: 'John Doe'};
 var method = input.toString().split('.');
 var nameObj = global[method[0]];
 var methodToCall = method[1];

 nameObj[methodToCall](some_data_array.name);
```

Mark the use of `global[]`. This is where it starts.

[edited] * Modified code to use `global` instead of `window` as being used in `nodejs`.

Comment: The thing is I can't use window because it works server-side with node.

Comment: @Codel96: That is why I wrote - you need to get the `scope` and my example was using `window` scope. You probably would have a different scope (namely `global`). I will change the code.

Comment: Ok thank's for the answer. I'm gonna try that. I think I'll still go with SLaks answer because it's easier to manipulate data but it helped me ;).

Comment: The scope generally is where you define `User` and in majority of the cases it is given by `this`.

Comment: Notice that providing the client a possibility to call *arbitrary* methods on `global` and its descendants is as bad as using `eval`.

Comment: Correct. That is why I had mentioned to get the scope. The code is to illustrate using @Codel96 's existing code which seems to be using global scope.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is access the global object.

This should work:

```
var User = {};
User.find = function(){
    return 1;
}

var input = 'User.find';
var some_data_array = {name: 'John Doe'};
var method = input.toString().split('.');
var nameObj = method[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() +method[0].substring(1);
var methodToCall = method[1];

"use strict";
var global = (1,eval)("this");
alert(global[nameObj][methodToCall](some_data_array));
```

Comment: It won't work in jsfiddle, run in console. Edit: I'm assuming this is because of how fiddle runs the JS, and it's not declaring `User` object within the global scope.

Comment: Here's what I get: `TypeError: Property 'connect' of object #<Object> is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get the desired result.  In this case it is very simple to just use an anonymous function, as follows, passing in the string parameter contained in **objName.name**:

```js
var f = function(oName){
  if (oName == 'John Doe') {
     return 1;
  }   
 };


 var objName = {name: 'John Doe'};
 
console.log( f( objName.name ) );
```

If the OP prefers to use an object's call method, the following code also will suffice:

```js
var myObj = {
  myFunc: function() {
    if (this.name == 'John Doe') {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}

var objName = {
  name: 'John Doe'
};

console.log(myObj.myFunc.call(objName));
```

A couple of things to note.  myObj calls its method myFunc() passing in the object parameter objName.  The purpose of **this** in the method is to read the property **name**, possessing that ability because of being bound to the object objName.