# How secure or insecure is this JavaScript code if run on the server (nodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, eval, code-injection

Curious as to what unforeseen issues this type of code might present, if executed on the server. Or if there are any non `eval` alternatives.

```
var a = {b:1, c:2, d:3, e:[1,2,3]};
(function(path) { return eval('this'+path) }).call(a, '.e[2]');
```

Comment: where does `path` come from? besides, `return this[path]` works

Comment: `path` comes in a param from client.

Comment: Are you sure `this[path]` works?

Comment: then it's very dangerous, slow, and unneeded, just use the array syntax shown.

Comment: if path doesn't have a dot, it will. you can use `this[path.slice(1)]` if it starts with a  dot... but inside eval, this==this outside. if your object is deeper, use a resolve() function.

Comment: yes that only works if `.` is the only dellimiter, but it won't if more complex cases like `.e[2].b[3].c`, etc.

Comment: Can you explain why it's dangerous and slow? I have read up on eval and I'm pretty sure I understand the basics, but I don't think it's slow, (the object a, in this case is not very large, and if there isn't a chance for eval to escape it's closure and access anything except the `this` object, which is the provided "a" object, then I don't see any security issues. But if someone can prove me wrong with proof I would like to learn...

Comment: try `path=".d=0;require('fs').unlink('./app.js');123"; eval('this'+path) });` (well, don't try it actually) eval itself is slower than normal code because it takes so much work to build and tear down a new environ, compared to a single prop lookup, which on V8 is near instant.

Comment: That's not how I run eval, eval is in a closure, also you could have provided a less harmful example. I've tried an alternative: `path=".d;console.log('hello'))" 
".d;console.log('hello'))"
(function(path) { return eval('this'+path) }).call(a, path);
VM413:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:2:37)
    at <anonymous>:2:47`

Comment: it looks like you'll need a try/catch too, which also slows down V8. i think your test "XSS" is mal-formed (an extra ")"), but i'm sure the right combo of escaping and nesting can execute arbitrary code. will anyone ever pull your card? maybe not, but why leave the trap door open?

Comment: Yes, with the correct path=".d;console.log('hello')", it prints "hello" in the console... some suggestions I got was to only allow `alphanumeric`, `[]` and `.`

Comment: don't play cat and mouse. do yourself a favor just get rid of the eval and use a resolve(). look up how to access object properties by a string, it's been answered a lot. godspeed.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `path` is a static value (`".e[2]"`) and `a` does not have any malicious accessors or so, there is nothing insecure here except that it's totally unnecessary.

However, if `path` does come from a client or some other untrusted source, then passing it to `eval` is the worst thing you can do. It can do everything that JS code can do in node - and that is enough to harm you severely.

And yes, there are [tons of non-eval alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572).

Comment: comments state that `path` is a value passed in from the client so it is far from static or secure.

Comment: @NeilSmithline: Thanks, this wasn't stated in the question. Updated my answer for that case.

Comment: Yes, I ended up going with `lodash` 3.9.*'s `_.get()` which does exactly what I need.