# How to access object children from string describing address

Tags: javascript

If I have an object like this...

```
var rooter = {
    name: 'Billy',
    lastName: 'Moon',
    height: '1.4m'
}
```

I can access the properties from variables like this...

```
var name = "name"
console.log(rooter[name])

var arb = "height"
console.log(rooter[arb])
```

Happy days!

However, if I have a more deeply nested object, and I want to get a leaf described by an address in a string...

```
var rooter = {
    user: {
        firstName: 'Billy',
        lastName: 'Moon',
        arbitrary: {
            namespace: {
                height: '1.4m'
            }
        }
    }
}


var name = "user.lastName"
console.log(rooter[name]) // does not work

var arb = "user.arbitrary.namespace.height"
console.log(rooter[arb]) // does not work
```

No dice :(

How can I access arbitrary object leaves from a string describing the path?

*EDIT*: Found method with underscore...

```
_.reduce(arb.split('.'), function(m, n){ return m[n] }, rooter)
```

and for IE 9 and above...

```
arb.split('.').reduce(function(m, n){ return m[n] }, rooter)
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338192/access-object-through-dot-syntax-string-path?rq=1

Comment: yes - looks like the same question - it is very hard to search for. I think the answer seems overly complex though - there must be a simpler way.

Comment: Question to the community, is _I don't like that answer_ a valid case for a duplicate question?

Comment: You can't really get simpler than using `.split` on your `"user.arbitrary.namespace.height"` strings, because object property access in JavaScript was built such that you have to use multiple bracket notations (`obj['prop1']['prop2']...`) if you have strings of your property names. I would encapsulate it in a function, as the answers below have done and the linked answer has done, so that you can write once and forget it.

Comment: @Mathletics The linked answer doesn't use a "good-looking" code (too short variable names).

Comment: [There's a huge lot of duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397052/1048572). And no, that solution is not complicated.

Comment: Sure, but now you're including a whole library for something that can be done simply. Potato/potato I guess.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I think I am going to go with `reduce` solution, and use shim where necessary (not in my case right now).

Comment: Actually, I think I might use the answer from the duplicate question, now I understand it a bit better

Comment: Or maybe the answer from @Scott actually - as it is very elegant, simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around a bit and found:
 [Access object child properties using a dot notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string)
which seems to be an answer to your question.

There are a few ways that you could go about accessing different descendants in a object.
For example, you could do rooter['name']['arbitrary']['namespace']['height'], in order to get the value of height. But this seems as thought it may not be exactly what you were looking for.

In that post, the answer ended up being that you would write a method of your own in order to do it, in which you would take in a string, delimited by dots and split it. Then you would find that element and return the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` (which is usually a bad idea):

```
eval('rooter.' + name);
```

Probably better way for doing this will be:

```
function namespace(namespaceString) {
    var parts = namespaceString.split('.'),
        parent = window,
        currentPart = '';    

    for(var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
        currentPart = parts[i];
        parent[currentPart] = parent[currentPart] || {};
        parent = parent[currentPart];
    }

    return parent;
}

console.log(namespace('rooter.user.firstName'));
```

Comment: I am not going to use eval...

Comment: Ok, so you have the second option :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code:

```
function access(obj, prop, defVal) {
    var objectNames = prop.split(".");

    var curObj = obj;

    for (var i = 0, len = objectNames.length; i < len; i++) {
        curObj = curObj[objectNames[i]];
        if (typeof curObj === 'undefined') {
            return defVal;
        }
    }
    return curObj;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NhZEb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

### Recursive method ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338192/access-object-through-dot-syntax-string-path?rq=1))

```
var rooter = { user: { firstName: 'Billy', lastName: 'Moon', arbitrary: { namespace: { height: '1.4m' } } } };

var arb = "user.arbitrary.namespace.height";

fromPathString = function(pathString, targetObject){
    pathString = pathString.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i < pathString.length; i++){
        targetObject = (targetObject[pathString[i]])? targetObject[pathString[i]] : targetObject[pathString[i]] = {};
    };
    return targetObject
}

console.log(fromPathString(arb, rooter))
```

### Reduce method

```
arb.split('.').reduce(function(m, n){ return m[n] }, rooter)
```

Because `.reduce` is not compatible with all browsers...

```
Feature Chrome  Firefox (Gecko) Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
Basic support   (Yes)   3.0 (1.9)   9   10.5    4.0
```

Shim for IE 9 and below... ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))

Just put before calling `.reduce` on any array...

```
if ('function' !== typeof Array.prototype.reduce) {
  Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback, opt_initialValue){
    'use strict';
    if (null === this || 'undefined' === typeof this) {
      // At the moment all modern browsers, that support strict mode, have
      // native implementation of Array.prototype.reduce. For instance, IE8
      // does not support strict mode, so this check is actually useless.
      throw new TypeError(
          'Array.prototype.reduce called on null or undefined');
    }
    if ('function' !== typeof callback) {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }
    var index, value,
        length = this.length >>> 0,
        isValueSet = false;
    if (1 < arguments.length) {
      value = opt_initialValue;
      isValueSet = true;
    }
    for (index = 0; length > index; ++index) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        if (isValueSet) {
          value = callback(value, this[index], index, this);
        }
        else {
          value = this[index];
          isValueSet = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!isValueSet) {
      throw new TypeError('Reduce of empty array with no initial value');
    }
    return value;
  };
}
```